# Proof of MiniMax Theorem (help with understanding an inequality)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory

Reading the proof of the first theorem [here](http://www.math.udel.edu/%7Eangell/minimax) (page 1), it says
Let
$$V(x,y)=\sum_i\sum_jp_iA_{ij}q_j$$
and let $(x^*,y^*)$ bean equalibrium pair. Than
$$v_B=min_ymax_xV(x,y)\le max_xV(x,y^*)=V(x^*,y^*)=min_y V(x^*,y)\le max_xmin_yV(x,y)=v_A$$

So far so good. But I do not understand the following.

> But, since we always have $v_A\le v_B$....

Why do we always have $v_A\le v_B$?

Comment: If it is any consolation, I have used this minimax relationship for over 3 decades and still need a moment's pause to remember which direction is 'for free'.

Comment: As an aside, minimax theorems give insight into many problems, duality, saddle points, etc. A useful addition to one's analysis toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse the conflicting bound & unbound variables.

Work through the following sequence.

$\min_y V(x,y) \le V(x,y)$, so $\min_y V(x,y) \le \max_x V(x,y)$, so
$\max_x \min_y V(x,y) \le \max_x V(x,y)$ and so
$\max_x \min_y V(x,y) \le \min_y \max_x V(x,y)$